# What does stuff like 1509429#1509429 mean inside permalink?

Tags: discussion

/questions/1509416/how-to-get-the-latest-record-among-3-different-table-in-mysql/1509429#1509429

I didn't see an element with id 1509429 but it still works,how?

Answer (score 8):

That is referring to an answer rather than a question.  The first number in the URL is the question number.  The name of the question can change if someone with authority (permission) edits the title, so I suspect that the value in the permalink is immaterial.

*Indeed, some playing with permalinks shows that the text portion is effectively ignored; you can reduce it to a single character, or remove all the characters, or remove the slash too.  Thus, all these get to this answer:*

- [What does stuff like 1509429#1509429 mean inside permalink?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24522/what-does-stuff-like-15094291509429-mean-inside-permalink/24523#24523)
- [What does stuff like 1509429#1509429 mean inside permalink?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24522/k/24523#24523)
- [What does stuff like 1509429#1509429 mean inside permalink?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24522//24523#24523)
- [What does stuff like 1509429#1509429 mean inside permalink?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24522/24523#24523)

The first of the two numbers separated by the '#' (hash) symbol is the answer number - as part of the URL, it instructs Stack Overflow to load the page with that answer on it (only really meaningful for questions with multiple pages of answers, but a link wouldn't be very *perm*anent if it broke once too many answers were posted).

The number after the hash (the URL "fragment") is *also* the answer number - but this time it instructs the *browser* to scroll that answer into view once the page has loaded.

Oh, and you're right - there's no element with an *id* set to the answer number; it's an honest-to-goodness *anchor!*

```
<a name="1509429"></a>
```

(Thanks to @shog9 for some previous additional information - the last couple of paragraphs, roughly.)

Comment: Can you explain what <a name="1509429"></a> exactly means?I've never seen the name attribute to work in the DOM other than posting values.

Comment: @unknown: see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1

Comment: Oh,I've never known about this before!

Comment: But this still doesn't explain why 1509429#1509429 is neccesary,which is my third comment to Jeff Atwood.

Comment: @Shore - Actually it does - **Step 1)** The request returns the question with the page selected for that answer (specified by `/1509429` - this doesn't happen if you leave this portion of the URL out), **Step 2)** The browser loads the page, and moves to the anchor specified by #1509429 - no need for any JavaScript to perform this action (which would be required if you left off the hash portion of the URL)

Comment: @shog9 - thanks for the assist.  I suspect you should be getting more of the credit than me. :D

Answer (score 1):

hint: one of these things can be seen by the server and the client browser, while the other can *only* be seen by the client browser.

Comment: I think you used url rewrite,can you tell me what's the url after rewriting?

Comment: Is it something like /questions?id=1#3212?

Comment: But I don't see the reason to twice the number like /1509429#1509429,isn't /1509429 enough?

Comment: `#1509429` directs browsers (even with JavaScript disabled) to scroll down to the named anchor point in the document.

Comment: What gnarf said, with the addition that this information is not passed to the server, and so it is necessary to include that tag a second time so the server knows which answer you're talking about.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn,if I can check a comment as the answer,I'll do it on you!

Answer (score 0):

The old way for bookmarks to work was with a named hyperlink, and this is the method that SOFU uses, for example:

```
<a name="24523"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Named anchors (`<a>` tags) are a way to link to specific parts of a page..

Say you have a long page, and in the middle, the following HTML:

```
<a name="1509429"></a>
```

When you navigate to http://example.com/mypage.htm#1509429 the browser will jump to where the above HTML is.

Simply put, the `#1509429` makes the browser scroll the appropriate answer, rather than the top of the page (as a normal link would)